A question about the L'Hôpital's rule
I am a school student and recently I learned about the L'Hôpital's rule. It states that
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)},$$
where $a$ is a constant. But there is something I never understood and I want to ask now.
Let's evaluate the limit
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x+1}.$$
According to this rule, we have that
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x+1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x'}{(x+1)'}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{1}=1.$$
But, if we plug $x=0$ into the limit, we will get something else:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{0}{0+1}=\frac{0}{1}=0\neq 1.$$
And, if we draw the graph of the function $y=\frac{x}{x+1}$, we will see that the real value of this limit is equal to 0.
So, the question is, where is my error?

You should have a look at the hypothesis of L'Hôpital's rule. You're missing some!

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{0}{0+1}=0$$

L'Hospital's Rule requires $f,g$ to satisfy certain conditions. These include $f(a)=g(a)=0$. So in your example we can't use it.

I didn't know that. Thank you!

These are the kinds of problems I face daily in teaching. Many students today do not fully understand how a theorem is constructed, nor do they grasp the underlying hypotheses. They want to apply a formula like L'Hôpital's rule without first understanding its conditions.

@Sebastiano: Many students today ... True, but it's always been true. That is, this is not a recent phenomenon (i.e. last 20 or 30 years), but in various forms probably goes back to Euclid's time. Probably even stone age times, such as when instructions for accurate spear throwing are not appropriately followed. Understanding how a theorem is constructed and grasping the underlying hypotheses is part of learning math, a part that often isn't seen until calculus, and sometimes not until later (e.g. in a "how to write proofs" transition-to-advanced-undergraduate math course).

@Ivan Borisyuk: Another often overlooked aspect is that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ NOT existing does not necessarily imply that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not exist. That is, L'Hôpital's rule is not an "if and only if" result.

@DaveL.Renfro You have given a counterexample $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$.

@DaveL.Renfro You're right that this issue isn't new and has been around for centuries. However, in the past, Italy produced many brilliant mathematicians, such as Fibonacci and Cardano, who were at the forefront of mathematical development. Unfortunately, today, Italian students are performing at much lower levels in mathematics, highlighting the need to focus more on understanding the foundations and logic of math, rather than just memorization and quick application.

@DaveL.Renfro  and Sebastiano  I taught introductory analysis for almost 50 years and have never understood the obsession with L'HR. The only justification perhaps is that it is an early chance to hammer home the fact that theorems have hypotheses as well as conclusions. Marking a L'HR question out of 10 I'd give 2 for the calculation, and 8 for checking properly that the hypotheses hold!

@ancient mathematician: Marking a L'HR question out of 10 I'd give 2 for the calculation, and 8 for checking properly that the hypotheses hold! --- For an analysis class perhaps, but in a U.S. Calculus 1 class, at least for me, test questions were typically "evaluate the following limits" with no indication of what method can be used, other than a possible hint for a difficult limit or instructions NOT to use, e.g. L'Hopital's rule, if we hadn't covered it yet (students often had taken some calculus in high school and had previously seen L'Hopital's rule). (continued)

When covering L'Hopital's rule (whose purpose also provided a useful review of differentiation short-cut rules), I always pointed out that we needed it to be a $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ indeterminate form (at the point of its application; often some rewriting was needed prior to this) and gave counterexamples like the OP's question. I also emphasized that it could not be used to determine a limit does not exist, but usually did not go through an example like $x^2\sin(1/x)$ (continued)

(but something a bit out-of-scope like this for a Calculus 1 class might be on a supplementary handout for interested students). On the other hand, for an undergraduate real analysis class, these theoretical issues (careful proof, subtle counterexamples, etc.) are the primary focus, and often even the only focus.

@DaveL.Renfro Thanks. Yes, I was teaching real analysis.


It is not just the limit for x->a for some constant a, it also works if a = +/- inf, and for the limit towards a+ or a-, so it applies for more cases.

It is a requirement that the two limits on the left side are either both 0, or both +/- inf. That’s not the case here because one limit is 0 and one is 1.


